# How to remove the next element after removal of parent in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have simplified my problem to the following markup:

```
<div id="A">
   <div id="B"></div>
   <div id="C"></div>
</div>
<br>
```

And JQuery JS as in:

```
$('#B').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().remove();
 }
```

It removes A and thats what I want. But I also want to remove the br tag that immediately follows the parent. I tried various combinations of parent(), first(), next() of parent(), parent().parent(), etc... No luck.

Comment: You should use `margin-bottom: 1em` instead of a `<br>`. Let CSS handle styling.

Comment: @4castle I am using inline-block divs and then using br to break to start a new row. Works. I am clearly not a CSS or HTML guru. Tried block and float but somehow did not work. Will the br for the use-case here not work in some browsers"?

Comment: Ah, in that case you may be able to use `float: left; clear: left;` on each of those divs instead of using `inline-block`. `<br>` works, but it's nicer to use CSS since you can cascade/override styles and such.

Comment: @4castle. Thanks. Tried ur approach. Works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use jQuery .is() check to check if the next element is a 
 and then remove it. Refer Below code and fiddle :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#B').click(function() {
    if($(this).parent().next().is('br')) {
      $(this).parent().next().remove()
    }
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/3xx2L20h/

Comment: So many answers... Tried yours, makes sense, works. Thanks.  I like the fact that I am checking if it is a 'br'

Comment: Can you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120247/upload-image-not-showing-in-request-header-using-formdata-file-api-and-jquery)

Comment: Sure, Let me check !

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#B').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().remove();
     $(this).parent().nextUntil(':not(br)').remove();
 }
```

Try this snippet

Answer (score 0):

You would select the next element and remove it as well (it may or may not be a `<br/>`.

```js
$('#B').click(function() {
  var nextElement = $(this).parent().next();
  $(nextElement).remove();
  $(this).parent().remove();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A"> A DIV 
   <div id="B"> B DIV</div>
   <div id="C"> C DIV</div>
</div>
<br/>
NEXT ELEMENT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#B').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().remove(); // Removes next element, br in your case
    $(this).parent().remove(); // Removes parent, #A in your case
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has a function for this kind of thing: [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addback/)

```
$(this).parent().nextUntil("div").addBack().remove();
```